# PHP MySqli - Subtract & Add & Echo if 0

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a simple loyalty program. In which users will be allotted a few Free visits.

so there's 2 fields One is"balance" which shows how many visits left and when they reach 0 it echo or show alert that u reach 0.

2nd is total which count total visits done by users.

This is what i tried but not getting the above solution:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

    $my_query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `countvisits` WHERE `id` = ".$id);

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($connection) > 0 ){

        $query = "UPDATE `countvisits` SET `balance` = `balance` - 1 And `TotalVisits` = `TotalVisits` + 1 WHERE `id` = ".$id;

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);   

        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Successfully Scanned")';
        echo '</script>';

       /* get new updated data */
       $new_query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `countvisits` WHERE `id` = '$id'");

    }else{
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("User Not Found")';
        echo '</script>';

        /* get new updated data */
    }
}
?>
```

above query only subtract and shows balance & doesnt add +1 to total visits
How can i achieve above results?

Comment: The question is *too vague*, please add more details to it.

Comment: both `balance` and `TotalVisits` column exiat in the same table `countvisits`?

Comment: yes both are in the same table

Comment: its very simple but am not getting it ...i just want to add -1 to balance & +1 to total visits...thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `And` in query use `,` as a seperator.

Like below:-

```
$query = "UPDATE `countvisits` SET balance = balance - 1, TotalVisits = TotalVisits + 1 WHERE `id` = ".$id;
```

NOTE:- your query is wide-open for SQL INJECTION. So try to use `prepared-statements` to prevent from it.

Reference:-

[mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

[PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

***You can check the balance first to see if it is 0 or not:-***

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

    $my_query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `countvisits` WHERE `id` = ".$id);

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($connection) > 0 ){

       $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($my_query);
       if($data['balance'] ==0){
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Balance become 0")';
        echo '</script>';
       }else{
            $query = "UPDATE `countvisits` SET balance = balance - 1, TotalVisits = TotalVisits + 1 WHERE `id` = ".$id;

            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);   

            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Successfully Scanned")';
            echo '</script>';

           /* get new updated data */
           $new_query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `countvisits` WHERE `id` = '$id'");
        }
    }else{
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("User Not Found")';
        echo '</script>';

        /* get new updated data */
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect ...thank you....how can i alert or echo  if balance field reach 0?

Comment: You need to check value at each time when you are doing query and when it become 0 add the alert code (use `if-else` condition).

Comment: will you please provide me an example as i am new to this?

Comment: @a2zbollywood  GLAD TO HEL YOU :):)

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
$query = "UPDATE `countvisits` SET `balance` = `balance` - 1 And `TotalVisits` = `TotalVisits` + 1 WHERE `id` = ".$id;
```

With this:

```
$query = "UPDATE `countvisits` SET `balance` = `balance` - 1, `TotalVisits` = `TotalVisits` + 1 WHERE `id` = ".$id;
```

When you update a table in sql the separator must be comma `,` not `and` keyword.

Comment: perfect ...how can i alert if balance field reach 0?

Comment: @Ciprian ah I see read your thing wrong :) guessing that's what caused the other downvote - I can't change unless you make an edit but will rm my comment :)